# Extract data from mongodb to api rest

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm doing an REST API where data is located in MongoDB. I've a GET service to extract some data to post it on angular. So, I'd like to select this data from my document (there're more of fields on this document):

```
 "tipoNIF" : [ 
        {
            "codigo" : "01",
            "descripcion" : "NIF"
        }, 
        {
            "codigo" : "02",
            "descripcion" : "CIF"
        }, 
        {
            "codigo" : "03",
            "descripcion" : "Pasaporte"
        }
    ]
```

I would like to response this data in a json. I only need the description, but it would like nice to send the codes and description.
I did it, but it doesn't work:

```
vuelta={}
i=0;
for testy in param.distinct('tipoNIF'):
    print(testy['codigo'], testy['descripcion'])
    #vuelta[]
    vuelta[i] = {testy['codigo'], testy['descripcion']}
    i=i+1
```

Debugging it, i can see this structure:
[Dict debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJYC0.png)

But I've this error: TypeError:

```
Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

Maybe it's no the best option to do this, there're my first steps with python... thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do here :: `param.distinct('tipoNIF')` ? Do you wanted to get all distinct arrays of `tipoNIF` from your collection(query would iterate thru all docs in collection & return data) ?

Comment: In this document I've many data, like 'tipoNIF' or 'typeCITY'. I would like to extract the data of tipoNIF when I push tipoNIF button on angular, or typeCITY when I push typeCITY on angular